# Array or table with one column in postgresql function returns

Tags: sql, postgresql

What is better to use array or table with one column in postgresql function returns? So, we have function_1 which returns data and function_2. In function_2 instead of using *join table_name* we can use *where values IN (array_name)*. Is there any difference in performance for a large set of data?

Comment: @Jakafa ... The database does not independently store arrays, so I don't understand the question.  If you need for data to be persisted, use a table.

Comment: This data is returning from function and should be used in another function for filtering. I do not need to save the data.

Comment: Why do you think you need to store that? You could use the result of a function directly inside the other function.

Comment: This relates to my other question. Greenplum doesn't let me call a function in SELECT. And now I see only one solution: use declare variable in which I assign value from another function. But I cannot assign a table to a variable (or can?). So I decided to pass an array.

Comment: What do you mean by `array_name`? Is the array another column of the table? Is it a variable inside the function? Where does the array data come from?

Comment: So you aren't actually using Postgres, but Greenplum?